# typify a list dynamically json.net, deserialization with reflection

Tags: c#, json, list, dynamic, reflection

I have a little problem.
I should deserialize a json through libraries json.net in c #.
I can not understand how you can switch typing the list in bold, of course, all using the reflection, because I'm doing a generic method.

Someone can give me an enlightment? or the solution :)

```
public static void insertTable(String json, String table)
{     
        using (localDBService db = new localDBService())
        {
            dynamic item = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("eStartService." + table));
            item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json); 

            try
            {
                var set = db.Set(item.GetType());
                set.Add(item);
                db.SaveChanges();
                log.Info("Scritto sul database dal metodo InsertTable");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Info("ERRORE DI SCRITTURA SUL DATABASE METODO : insertTable");
                throw ex;
            }
        }    
}
```

**ERROR: The entity type JArray is not part of the model for the current context.**

thanks

My need is to be able to read the json , de-serializing in your object dynamically as you see me now ... and from that mistake that I glued .
any solution ?

Comment: I have 2 problems here, first what's with `Type type = serviceString.GetType();` currently it always returns type of string, can you get your desired type from a service or not?, second json.net already supports deserialization in a anonymous or dynamic object but my question is how you are going to use your list when you don't know what is inside it, if you could answer these 2 question with usage examples for both of them, I believe we can suggest a solution.

Comment: I would typify the list that returns the json.net dynamically .. which means that the object type dynamically I said! It is so clear?

Comment: it is understandable what I could use ?

Comment: do you want to resolve a type dynamically or create a type at runtime?

Comment: why can't you use dynamic instead, is there any particular reason?

Comment: with the dynamic I instantiate a typed list List < gettype > , using dynamics I returned the item , I do not understand why

Comment: did you try something like `dynamic dyno = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(value);
            var id=dyno[0].IdCustomer;
            var idString= id.ToString();` ? (I wrote it based on your json sample in the question)

Comment: if I do so the data is taken but they are all on one line , I would have to split the object parameters , since it will be a generic method , to add to the model with the entity framework, I simply do `db.Add ( dyno [ 0 ] ) ;` but this does not work because `dyno [ 0 ]` is not subdivided property . How can I fix ? ideas ?

Comment: there are some auto mappers for this task https://github.com/randyburden/Slapper.AutoMapper

Comment: but from what you said, I believe you have access to Type FullName at run-time and actually you don't need to create the type at run-time, correct? in this case you can resolve the type with `Type.GetType` I updated the answer based on this method to see if it fits. and based in my understandings this it what you intended to do in `serviceString.GetType();  ` so it should be changed to `Type.GetType(serviceString)`

Comment: I edited all my question , what is my code , as well as my generic method , even with my mistake . How do you see the error is that I do not recognize the object

Comment: you have been very kind , works a treat ! I really lost in a glass of water !
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We should create a generic Type of `List<>` based on a specific type like

```
var listType = typeof (List<>).MakeGenericType(type);
```

here is a complete example of De-serializing a json value to a list with a custom type:

```
    public static void insertTable(String json, String table)
    {
        using (localDBService db = new localDBService())
        {
            var tableType = Type.GetType("eStartService." + table);
            var list = DeserializeList(json, tableType);

            try
            {
                var set = db.Set(tableType);

                foreach (var item in list)
                    set.Add(item);
                db.SaveChanges();
                log.Info("Scritto sul database dal metodo InsertTable");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Info("ERRORE DI SCRITTURA SUL DATABASE METODO : insertTable");
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }


    private static IList DeserializeList( string value,Type type)
    {
        var listType = typeof (List<>).MakeGenericType(type);
        var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(value, listType);
        return list as IList;
    }
```

Comment: my problem is that I do not know that class will, that I have about 30 items, which amount to Foo that you put it. to me it would like Foo was dynamic ideas ..?

Comment: @Developer yes, Foo is just a sample as you can see in the example I just passed the **Foo Type** to `DeserializeList` method, we can pass any other type instead

Comment: I can take with the Foo reflecfion? or rather .. how can I do with the Foo dynamic reflection? maybe I'm missing out on a glass of water

Comment: My need is to do class `Foo {return something.getType (); }` It's possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem correctly, in the answer Foo is an example of `serviceString.GetType();`. if you want to directly access to a generic list of your type from `list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<**type**>>(json);` I should say there is no easy way to do it as you don't know the type at compile time (even if you manage to deserialize it based on provided solution), may be generic constrains or even `dynamic` object help you to access some shared properties/methods from deserialized types

Comment: i have edit the question, maybe we are close to the solution , you have ideas ?